# Different coloured print strings in python - IDLE

Tags: python, colors, ide, python-idle

I'm using IDLE to just create a short, basic text adventure game. the methods I try work in other editors such as Repl.it or canopy, but I prefer the use of IDLE as I just like the simplicity of it, and that it doesn't require an Internet connection to access.

I won't mention the methods I tried, as I may have just been approaching them in the entirely wrong way, or maybe IDLE just simply doesn't have the functionality of other editors, but I just want to make the text in the game clearer to distinguish. For example, below is a short segment:

```
import time

print ("Welcome Traveller!") 
time.sleep(1)
def name_identify():
    print () 
    name_input = input ("What is your name? ").lower() 
    name_input = name_input.title() 
    time.sleep(0.75)
    def name_confirm(): 
        print ()
        print ("So %s is your name then?" % name_input)
```

Where the questions such as

```
name_input = input ("What is your name? ").lower()
```

appear in a different colour, or **bold**/*italic* even. As things similar to

```
print ("\x1B[3mHello World\x1B[23m")
```

and

```
print ("\033[1;31m""Hello world")
```

don't work, I assume this function is not naturally supported, so I ask, if it is possible to either A, make it supported, so this method, or similar work, or B, another option which does make changes at least similar to what I seek?

It would be very helpful if anyone could provide me with a way to do this, or at the very least an editor which is close in simplicity (design wise) to IDLE and does support the functions I seek. The version of python I am currently using is 3.6.1.

Thanks in advance, and I apologise if my wording confuses you, just ask about what confused you and I will attempt to clarify. Using Windows with the Idle Shell.

Due to the limitations of some python environments, I just used Tkinter to create an interactive procedurally generated script which you can scroll along as if it were the shell, with the added bonus of adding pictures for more depth.

Comment: Your commands work in the linux terminal. You probably need to verify for the kind of console you are using.

Comment: The issue is not the editor but the terminal or console where you direct your output.  IDLE's shell is designed for developing programs, not for running them.  You should specify your OS.  If you run your program (without IDLE) in unix, color is, as 'silgon' said, usually no problem as the console window should emulate a *color* terminal.  On Windows, the console window (Command Prompt) emulates a decades-old black and white terminal.  The workaround has been described in answers to other questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know what you are going through right now, but there is no benefit to make text colored or bold in python without GUI. If somehow you manage to do it it will turn back to normal text when you make the file to exe format. I have wasted a week on this.

It only makes sense when you are reach GUI programming. Tkinter would be a good place to start.

Its does not matter on the IDE but on the compiler.

In tkinter its a matter of seconds

```
  lab_practice = label(text = "practice",fg = "red#the foreground color",bg = "yellow",font = ("Arial",40))
```

Comment: even without a GUI, the clarity of different colored text helps while looking over the text of the game in tests, even if it doesn't last when turned into an executable file. 

And suppose I did end up with a GUI using Tkinter(as I was looking as using it to add some images and clickable buttons), even then how would I change the color of the text, as I didn't look too deeply into it.

Comment: If one runs a program in a color terminal emulator that responds to text color change commands, coloring text makes complete sense.  The color is in the output, as commanded, and the coding for the color does *not* disappear when the code is saved.  If one edits python code in a programming editor, such as IDLE, color syntax is *very* helpful even though the color disappears when the window is closed.  The editor's color generating code does not disappear.  That said (or your opening paragraph removed), a gui is a great way to make a Windows or cross-platform colored application.